# In cypress, how do I wait for a page to load?

Tags: cypress

Don't tell anyone, but our app is not yet single-page. I can [wait on a given XHR request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias) by giving the route an alias, but **how do I wait until some navigation completes and the browser is safely on a new page?**

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304163/927631)?

Comment: Was I ever this naive? The question betrays a total misunderstanding of the main selling point of Cypress. Cypress manages all this. It waits for an assertion to become true before passing to the next one. You can control the timeout, but the defaults are reasonable. This should all just work.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add some assert inside:

```js
cy.click('#someButtonToNavigateOnNewPage');

cy.location('pathname', {timeout: 60000})
  .should('include', '/newPage');

cy.click('#YouAreOnNewPage');
```

You can change default timeout - by default it's 4000 ms (4 secs) - to ensure that user navigated the page. I've put a big number here - 60,000 ms - because I'm sure that 99% of users will leave if they do not have page loaded after 1 min.

Comment: How or where to add waiting period?

Answer (score 0):

Add some assertion using `.should` statement and validate page title or heading

```
cy.visit('/dashboard').click();
cy.title().should('eq', 'Dashboard'); // page tab title
```

Answer (score -1):

as an addition to @igor answer

add an assertion to the expected page content also

for example :

```
cy.get('#SomeElementOnThePage').should('exist').click();
```

Comment: cy.get() have already build-in assertion to check if element exist in DOM. Please read https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Assertions