# Cypress - how to not wait for a page load event?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

In contrast to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553489/in-cypress-how-do-i-wait-for-a-page-to-load), how do I don't wait for a page `load` event. I have a situation where a click generates a form submit and starts a download. Cypress then waits for a page `load` event which never occurs.

I've tried:

```
setTimeout(
  cy.window().then(win => {
    win.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'))
  }), 5000);
cy.get('#btn').click();
//and also tried:
cy.get('form.excel-data').submit() //redirect to server
//and:
cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  win.removeEventListener('load');
})
cy.get('#btn').click();
```

** I know about the best practices and how I shouldn't download to test `href`s etc... And still my question stands.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on the application side:

```
//form submit()...
if (window.Cypress) {
  setTimeout(() => location.reload(), 3000);
}
```

This reloaded the app after the submit happened and the file was downloaded. While it isn't perfect, it works and isn't affecting the application. Many other things I've tried on Cypress like catching the exception, didn't work either.

Comment: this is not working for me.  well in my case my tests passed and everything done and i dont  want to wait for new page to load i just want to ignore it

Please explain how I can do this 
Reason there is 1 api call that actually loading after some time now I dont want to want for this api I just want to ignore all loading and pass my test

Comment: @Mehran did you try all the above options in the question? I don't have any more suggestions...

Comment: yea I try but its not working still waiting for page load :( and at the end through error not load

Comment: perhaps `try{} catch{}` ?

Comment: the last thing u never wanna do is a try catch in your test case, that makes it no different from a dev code

Comment: If it's the last thing you never wanna do, is it the first..? ;)
Anyways, I agree it's not an ideal solution, but automation code is also dev code...