# How do you reliably wait for page idle in cypress.io test

Tags: angular, testing, web, cypress

When using cypress.io to test an angular web page, whats the best / most reliable way to detect when the page is fully loaded and idle. Not just the onload event. Needs to include all XHR requests, angular digest cycles complete and all rendering complete including all animations complete.

The reason is that at this point I want to test that the page does NOT contain an element and cant test that until all the above is fully complete.

Comment: would [this work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304163/927631)?

Comment: Thanks for the input Dwelle. This would work for some of the cases above, but I'm not very happy about changing the code just for the tests to work and also stripping this code in production then means that we are not testing the exact code that is in production. Our app has thousands of controllers, directives and services and I'm looking for a single method to detect when the page is idle. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10):

For the record what we did for this (**for AngularJS**) was to add a new `waitforpageidle` command that can be used like this:

```js
cy.waitforpageidle();
```

Typescript is as follows:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
    "waitforpageidle",
    () => {
        console.warn("Waiting for page idle state");

        const pageIdleDetector = new PageIdleDetector();

        pageIdleDetector.WaitForPageToBeIdle();
    }
);
```

Where the PageIdleDetector is as follows:

```js
export class PageIdleDetector
{   
    defaultOptions: Object = { timeout: 60000 };

    public WaitForPageToBeIdle(): void
    {
        this.WaitForPageToLoad();
        this.WaitForAngularRequestsToComplete();
        this.WaitForAngularDigestCycleToComplete();
        this.WaitForAnimationsToStop();
    }

    public WaitForPageToLoad(options: Object = this.defaultOptions): void
    {
        cy.document(options).should((myDocument: any) =>
        {
            expect(myDocument.readyState, "WaitForPageToLoad").to.be.oneOf(["interactive", "complete"]);
        });
    }

    public WaitForAngularRequestsToComplete(options: Object = this.defaultOptions): void
    {
        cy.window(options).should((myWindow: any) =>
        {
            if (!!myWindow.angular)
            {
                expect(this.NumberOfPendingAngularRequests(myWindow), "WaitForAngularRequestsToComplete").to.have.length(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public WaitForAngularDigestCycleToComplete(options: Object = this.defaultOptions): void
    {
        cy.window(options).should((myWindow: any) =>
        {
            if (!!myWindow.angular)
            {
                expect(this.AngularRootScopePhase(myWindow), "WaitForAngularDigestCycleToComplete").to.be.null;
            }
        });
    }

    public WaitForAnimationsToStop(options: Object = this.defaultOptions): void
    {
        cy.get(":animated", options).should("not.exist");
    }

    private getInjector(myWindow: any)
    {
        return myWindow.angular.element(myWindow.document.body).injector();
    }

    private NumberOfPendingAngularRequests(myWindow: any)
    {
        return this.getInjector(myWindow).get('$http').pendingRequests;
    }

    private AngularRootScopePhase(myWindow: any)
    {
        return this.getInjector(myWindow).get("$rootScope").$$phase;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks great, but isn't this code for AngularJS (and not Angular 2+)

Comment: @Benoît Angular2 does not have a digest cycle

Answer (score 6):

You can make Cypress wait for any request to complete before it proceeds. So if you want to wait for all XHR of a certain page, you can do the following for each of them. How long it waits is defined by the [responseTimeout configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts).

```js
cy.server();
cy.route('**/api/getData').as('getData');
cy.visit('/home');
cy.wait('@getData');
```

Or to wait for several routes:

```js
cy.server();
cy.route('**/api/getData').as('getDataX');
cy.route('**/api/getData').as('getDataY');

cy.visit('/home');
cy.wait(['@getDataX', '@getDataY']);
```

[Cypress best practices: Unnecessary-Waiting.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting)

[Cypress docs on wait Alias.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias)

Comment: This isn't useful when you have dozens of requests going out, and the last one is the one you wanted to wait for.

Comment: Understandable, also still not very useful. I've been working around this problem recently, where the developers make the application perform a batch request when it detects that the app's cache is not set. If I were to add enough routes/waits to match the number of requests that go out in this case, there are two things that would be wrong:
1. The test would be very brittle.
2. The intention of waiting is to wait until the application is done loading and ready. If a request fails in that time, waiting will also fail.

Our work around was to expose a loading flag for cypress to use.

Comment: Maybe the test would be brittle because the application is also brittle? These kinds of problems might be like a "code smell", meaning that it might be a sign that the app architecture could be improved.

Comment: That's a fair statement. My scenario does involve a brittle (legacy) application, where making changes usually involves office warfare. It's not optimal, but you gotta do what you can to get to the good place. I'd love to discuss this further with you, though maybe... on a meta channel? I have no idea how that works.

Comment: I wish I had time to discuss and analyse the issues you are facing, but I think it will work better if you can structure the issues you are still facing as a SO question and maybe the community is able to help.

Answer (score 4):

**For Angular (2+)**

The previous answer relates to AngularJS. For Angular 2+, you can use this other solution.

*Disclaimer* : In most cases Cypress waiting mechanism is sufficient. But if you really need the application to stabilise (ie: that all requests and Async Tasks like debounces have fulfilled) you can use this command.

- In your src/main.ts, add the following shortcut method to the window object :

```
    /**
     * Used by Cypress.waitForAngularIdle() (in commands.ts) to wait for all Pending request to finish
     */
    function ngIsStable() {
      const test = (window as any).getAngularTestability(window.document.querySelector('body div')) as Testability // you need to select an element managed by Angular. Usually any div in your html body

      const stable = test.isStable()
      //if (!stable) {   // this console.log block is just for information, you can remove it
      console.log('Angular is ' + (stable ? '' : 'NOT ') + 'stable:', {
        pendingRequestCount: test.getPendingRequestCount(),
        _pendingCount: (test as any)._pendingCount,
        pendingTasks: (test as any).getPendingTasks(),
      })
      // }
      return stable
    }

    window['ngIsStable'] = ngIsStable;
```

- In your Cypress commands.ts file :

```
    function waitForAngularIdle() { 
        cy.window().invoke('ngIsStable').should('be.true')
    }
    Cypress.Commands.add('waitForAngularIdle', waitForAngularIdle);
```

- In your Cypress index file index.d.ts (for typescript compilation)

```
    declare namespace Cypress {
      interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        waitForAngularIdle()
      }
    }
```

- In your Cypress specs when you need Cypress to wait for your angular application to stabilize :

```
    cy.waitForAngularIdle()
```