# cypress: unable to access app from window object

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I need to access my vuex store in cypress tests, so i added the app to the window object in my main.js:

```
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");

window.vueApp = app;
```

And then i try to access it in my login command (commands.js):

```
cy
    .request({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/login",
      body: {},
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("administrator:12345678")
      }
    })
    .then(resp => {
      console.log("app:", window.vueApp);
      ...
      window.localStorage.setItem("aq-username", "administrator");
    });
```

but it's always undefined, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window` that you're using refers to the cypress runner `window`. If you want to access the `window` of your AUT (application under test), use [`cy.window()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window.html#Syntax) command.

Or you can use `cy.state('window')` which returns the window object synchronously, but this is undocumented and may change in the future.

Related: if you want to access your AUT in the dev console, you'll need to switch the context to `Your app...`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i tried `cy.window().its("vueApp")` and i get an error that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Try checking your window object in the console as shown above. Is it possible your `main.js` isn't loaded at the time of your `cy.window()` command executes?

Comment: You can wait for your `main.js` to be loaded using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304163/927631) (kinda clunky.. dunno of better way to do it yet).

Comment: No need, all i needed was to add `cy.visit("/")` to init the app