# Difficulty accessing window object in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to access the window object of my App in Cypress in the following manner.

```
cy.url().should('include', '/home').then(async () => {
    const window = await cy.window();
    console.log(window);
});
```

The above method is not working for me as `window` is returned as `undefined`.

However, the answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122236/cypress-unable-to-access-app-from-window-object) states the following:

> Or you can use cy.state('window') which returns the window object
>   synchronously, but this is undocumented and may change in the future.

This method **does** return the window value successfully.

```
cy.url().should('include', '/home').then(async () => {
    const window = cy.state('window');
    console.log(window);
});
```

**As the answer suggests, cy.state('window') is undocumented so I would still rather use cy.window(). Is there any reason why it's returning undefined? (I started learning cypress today.)**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This comes up frequently. Cypress has some documentation stating [Commands are not Promises](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Not-Promises). I did a write up using a custom command to force a Command Chain to behave like a promise, but it is still experimental and nuanced.

First I'll give your example almost verbatim to what you're trying to accomplish:

```js
cy.url().should('include', '/home').then(() => {
  cy.window().then(win => {
    console.log(win) // The window of your app, not `window` which is the Cypress window object
  })
})
```

Your example could be written a number of ways, but maybe explaining a bit how Cypress works will help more.

Cypress has something called "Commands" that return new "Chainers". It is fluid syntax like JQuery:

```js
// fill and submit form
cy
  .get('#firstname')
  .type('Nicholas')
  .get('#lastname')
  .type('Boll')
  .get('#submit')
  .click()
```

You can (and should) break up chains to be more like sentences:

```js
// fill and submit form
cy.get('#firstname').type('Nicholas')
cy.get('#lastname').type('Boll')
cy.get('#submit').click()
```

You might have guessed that all Cypress Chainer commands are asynchronous. They have a `.then`, but they aren't actually promises. Cypress commands actually enqueue. Cypress hooks into mocha's lifecycle to make sure a `before`, `beforeEach`, `it`, `afterEach`, `after` block waits until Cypress commands are no longer enqueued before continuing.

Let's look at this example:

```js
it('should enter the first name', () => {
  cy.get('#firstname').type('Nicholas')
})
```

What actually happens is Cypress sees the `cy.get` Command and enqueues the `get` command with the argument `'#firstname'`. This immediately (synchronously) returns execution to the test. Cypress then sees the `cy.type` command with the argument `'Nicholas'` and returns immediately to the test. The test is technically done at this point since there is no `done` callback and no Promise was returned. But Cypress hooks into the lifecycle of mocha and doesn't release the test until enqueued commands are completed.

Now that we have 2 enqueued commands and the test is waiting for Cypress to release the test, the `get` command is popped off the queue. Cypress will try to find an element on the page with an id of `firstname` until it finds it or times out. Assuming it finds the element, it will set a state variable called `subject` (`cy.state('subject')`, but don't rely on that). The next enqueued command `type` will grab the previous `subject` and attempt to type each key from the string `'Nicholas'` one at a time with a default delay of 50ms until the string is done. Now there are no more enqueued commands and Cypress releases the test and the runner continues to the next test.

That was a bit simplified - Cypress does a lot more to make sure `.type` only runs on elements that can receive focus and are interactable, etc.

Now, knowing this, you can write your example a bit more simply:

```js
cy.url().should('include', '/home')

// No need for `.then` chaining or async/await. This is an enqueued command
cy.window().then(win => {
  console.log(win)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53058423/3209523) is good but not really showing me what is necessary.

For me, it is awesome that everything is synchronous and you can do things like

```
let bg1 = null;

// simply store the value of a global object in the DOM
cy.window().then((win) => {
  bg1 = win.myPreciousGlobalObj.color;
});

// Do something that changes a global object
cy.get('a.dropdown-toggle').contains('File').click();

cy.window().then((win) => {
  const bg2 = win.myPreciousGlobalObj.color;
  // check if nodes and edges are loaded
  expect(bg1 != bg2).to.eq(true);
});
```

Here the interesting thing is even the things inside the `then` blocks are synchronous. This is so useful.

Comment: This is not really correct, it may appear synchronous because it's quick - but if you place `console.log()` at the end of the test and also within the callbacks you will see the callbacks (and the Cypress commands) execute after the test code finishes. If you really want it to be synchronous, use `const win = cy.state('window')`.

Comment: Oo  you might be right, I should try and update my answer. Thanks

Comment: it is very strange. If I use `cy.log`, it seems like everything is synchronous but if I use `console.log` things are not sync like you said